# How to track online and offline app usage duration on Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

I already have a service that sends how much time by minutes a user was online or offline every 15 mins and only after the state has changed from the previous one (online to offline or vice versa). So, basically, I can see the minutes count as a value when selecting a parameter, for example, ONLINE_TIME (in screenshot called TIME), and see events in the last 30 mins with values of how much time the user was online by minutes.[image]

My main goal is to see in Firebase, how much percent time of the day users was online and offline. Any ideas on how could I achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: Can't use custom events. Submit events when the user is on/off with the respective timestamp. So you can get an average.

Comment: @HeshanSandeepa Basically I want to sum up these values and show them as a percentage of online (TIME parameter) and offline (OFFLINE_TIME parameter). I don't really understand your idea.

Comment: You can use custom events. Submit a custom event when the user  open & clsoe the app + connection is on & off with the respective timestamp. So you can get an average